# video insertado en mi web alojado en Mega no adelanta ni atrasa

Tags: php, wordpress, progressbar, cloud, html-video

Estoy haciendo pruebas en mi web para videos alojados en Mega

Reproduce bien, pero el problema es que no se puede adelantar ni atrasar en la barra de tiempo, porque vuelve a iniciar el vídeo.

Esta es la página de prueba que he hecho en el que podeís observar lo que he dicho: https://videos.2000peliculassigloxx.com/prueba/

En el cpanel tengo una carpeta con dos archivos:

index.php

```html
<?php
require_once('mega.class.php');
$megafile = new MEGA('http://mega.nz/#'.$_GET['id']);`
//$megafile->download();
`// OR`
$megafile->stream_download(); // to download using streams
?>
```

mega.class.php

```html
<?php
/**
 * mega.nz downloader
 * Require mcrypt, curl
 * @license GNU GPLv3 http://opensource.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
 */
class MEGA
{
    private $seqno, $f;
    /**
     * Class constructor
     * @param string $file_hash File hash, coming after # in mega URL
     */
    function __construct($file_hash)
    {
        $this->seqno = 0;
        $this->f = $this->mega_get_file_info($file_hash);
    }
    function a32_to_str($hex)
    {
        return call_user_func_array('pack', array_merge(array('N*'), $hex));
    }
    function aes_ctr_decrypt($data, $key, $iv)
    {
        return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, 'ctr', $iv);
    }
    function base64_to_a32($s)
    {
        return $this->str_to_a32($this->base64urldecode($s));
    }
    function base64urldecode($data)
    {
        $data .= substr('==', (2 - strlen($data) * 3) % 4);
        $data = str_replace(array('-', '_', ','), array('+', '/', ''), $data);
        return base64_decode($data);
    }
    function str_to_a32($b)
    {
        // Add padding, we need a string with a length multiple of 4
        $b = str_pad($b, 4 * ceil(strlen($b) / 4), "\0");
        return array_values(unpack('N*', $b));
    }
    /**
     * Handles query to mega servers
     * @param array $req data to be sent to mega
     * @return type
     */
    function mega_api_req($req)
    {
        $ch = curl_init('https://g.api.mega.co.nz/cs?id=' . ($this->seqno++)/* . ($sid ? '&sid=' . $sid : '') */);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode(array($req)));
        $resp = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $resp = json_decode($resp, true);
        return $resp[0];
    }
    function aes_cbc_decrypt($data, $key)
    {
        return mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $data, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, "\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0");
    }
    function mega_dec_attr($attr, $key)
    {
        $attr = trim($this->aes_cbc_decrypt($attr, $this->a32_to_str($key)));
        if (substr($attr, 0, 6) != 'MEGA{"') {
            return false;
        }
        return json_decode(substr($attr, 4), true);
    }
    /**
     * Downloads file from megaupload
     * @param string $as_attachment Download file as attachment, default true
     * @param string $local_path Save file to specified by $local_path folder
     * @return boolean True
     */
    function download($as_attachment = true, $local_path = null)
    {
        $ch = curl_init($this->f['binary_url']);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        $data_enc = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $data = $this->aes_ctr_decrypt($data_enc, $this->a32_to_str($this->f['k']), $this->a32_to_str($this->f['iv']));
        if ($as_attachment) {
            //die(var_dump($this->f['attr']['n']));
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"{$this->f['attr']['n']}\"");
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
            header("Content-Length: " . $this->f['size']);
            header('Pragma: no-cache');
            header('Expires: 0');
            print $data;
            return true;
        } else {
            file_put_contents($local_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->f['attr']['n'], $data);
            return true;
        }
        /* $file_mac = cbc_mac($data, $k, $iv);
          print "\nchecking mac\n";
          if (array($file_mac[0] ^ $file_mac[1], $file_mac[2] ^ $file_mac[3]) != $meta_mac) {
          echo "MAC mismatch";
          } */
    }
    function get_chunks($size)
    {
        $chunks = array();
        $p = $pp = 0;
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 8 && $p < $size - $i * 0x20000; $i++) {
            $chunks[$p] = $i * 0x20000;
            $pp = $p;
            $p += $chunks[$p];
        }
        while ($p < $size) {
            $chunks[$p] = 0x100000;
            $pp = $p;
            $p += $chunks[$p];
        }
        $chunks[$pp] = ($size - $pp);
        if (!$chunks[$pp]) {
            unset($chunks[$pp]);
        }
        return $chunks;
    }
    /**
     * Downloads file from megaupload as a stream (useful if you want to implement megaupload proxy)
     * @param string $as_attachment Download file as attachment, default true
     * @param string $local_path Save file to specified by $local_path folder
     * @return boolean True
     */
    function stream_download($as_attachment = true, $local_path = null)
    {
        if ($as_attachment) {
            header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=\"{$this->f['attr']['n']}\"");
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
            header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
            header("Content-Length: " . $this->f['size']);
            header('Pragma: no-cache');
            header('Expires: 0');
        } else {
            $destfile = fopen($local_path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $this->f['attr']['n'], 'wb');
        }
        $cipher = mcrypt_module_open(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, '', 'ctr', '');
        mcrypt_generic_init($cipher, $this->a32_to_str($this->f['k']), $this->a32_to_str($this->f['iv']));
        $chunks = $this->get_chunks($this->f['size']);
        $protocol = parse_url($this->f['binary_url'], PHP_URL_SCHEME);
        $opts = array(
            $protocol => array(
                'method' => 'GET'
            )
        );
        $context = stream_context_create($opts);
        $stream = fopen($this->f['binary_url'], 'rb', false, $context);
        $info = stream_get_meta_data($stream);
        $end = !$info['eof'];
        foreach ($chunks as $length) {
            $bytes = strlen($buffer);
            while ($bytes < $length && $end) {
                $data = fread($stream, min(1024, $length - $bytes));
                $buffer .= $data;
                $bytes = strlen($buffer);
                $info = stream_get_meta_data($stream);
                $end = !$info['eof'] && $data;
            }
            $chunk = substr($buffer, 0, $length);
            $buffer = $bytes > $length ? substr($buffer, $length) : '';
            $chunk = mdecrypt_generic($cipher, $chunk);
            if ($as_attachment) {
                print $chunk;
                ob_flush();
                ob_clean();
            } else
                fwrite($destfile, $chunk);
        }
        // Terminate decryption handle and close module
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($cipher);
        mcrypt_module_close($cipher);
        fclose($stream);
        if (!$as_attachment)
            fclose($destfile);
        return true;
        /* $file_mac = cbc_mac($data, $k, $iv);
          print "\nchecking mac\n";
          if (array($file_mac[0] ^ $file_mac[1], $file_mac[2] ^ $file_mac[3]) != $meta_mac) {
          echo "MAC mismatch";
          } */
    }
    private function mega_get_file_info($hash)
    {
        preg_match('/\!(.*?)\!(.*)/', $hash, $matches);
        $id = $matches[1];
        $key = $matches[2];
        $key = $this->base64_to_a32($key);
        $k = array($key[0] ^ $key[4], $key[1] ^ $key[5], $key[2] ^ $key[6], $key[3] ^ $key[7]);
        $iv = array_merge(array_slice($key, 4, 2), array(0, 0));
        $meta_mac = array_slice($key, 6, 2);
        $info = $this->mega_api_req(array('a' => 'g', 'g' => 1, 'p' => $id));
        if (!$info['g']) die('No such file on mega. Maybe it was deleted.');
        return array('id' => $id, 'key' => $key, 'k' => $k, 'iv' => $iv, 'meta_mac' => $meta_mac, 'binary_url' => $info['g'], 'attr' => $this->mega_dec_attr($this->base64urldecode($info['at']), $k), 'size' => $info['s']);
    }
    /**
     * Returns file information
     * @return array File information
     */
    public function file_info()
    {
        return $this->f;
    }
}
?>
```

Yo creo que es cuestión de modificar algo en el archivo mega.class.php pero no me doy cuenta. Como dije antes lo que pretendo es que el vídeo se pueda atrasar o adelantar al minuto específico que quiera el usuario